# MYSQLI - What is the best solution to split my data from mysqli_fetch_assoc?

Tags: mysqli, split

I would like to know what is the best way to **split** the **data** after a **select all** in a database with **mysqli** - please don't answer to add a where clause, because I can't in that situation, I NEED to manage data AFTER the query -.
So, I want to split the data in the **mysqli_fetch_assoc**.
What is the best method ? Is there a function to do that ? I need to do it manually with a for ? Is there an other easy solution to do it properly ?

Thanks for the help.

My code : (just an exemple, not the real code)

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
$exec = mysqli_query($db, $select);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec);
// Now with a do while() I can display all the data
// But I want to display only 10 rows for exemple
// -> What is the best solution to split my data here ? <-
do{
    // some html code here
} 
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec))
```

Comment: `break` your `while` loop after 10 iterations...!?

Comment: If i want to display the data from middle, it is not possible. Break the while include start with line 1 from the array in fetch_assoc. So it's not the solution.

Comment: Then `continue` in the loop until you hit your desired iteration to skip initial rows...!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an other easy solution to do it properly ?

Definitely.

And it's fairly simple, and no WHERE clause required. Instead, you have to add **LIMIT** clause:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 10";
$exec = mysqli_query($db, $select);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec)) {
    // some html code here
}
```

Comment: My code is just minimize. My select is not a real select all, I work with 15 table so I don't want to make 100 request per second. I prefer to do only one request, and after that manage my results to display only what I want. Moreover I know LIMIT clause but you are not answering to the real question.